# Updating Twitter status

Tags: php, twitter

I am trying to write a simple script to publish to my Twitter feed. The problem is, I have only come across two ways when Googling:

1. Using curl, which apparently is no longer supported.
2. Using OAuth, which requires registering applications and multiple users

I have one, and only one, Twitter account that I need to update, so I am not looking for something as complicated and robust as OAuth. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

To elaborate on my question since OAuth seems to be my only option...

My website has an administration area where there are many administrators, and when certain administrative tasks are executed, I want to post to the site's Twitter account. This will be a single Twitter account, not the administrator's personal account, so the whole 'Allow' and 'Deny' OAuth thing I see in most examples doesn't really apply as no user will ever be logged into the account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the quick update url:

> https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?source=webclient&text=I%27m+reading+http%3A%2F%2Fplanetozh.com%2Fblog

Or if you really MUST do it without the user's input, use one of the many twitter libraries that are available or an easy tutorial.

> http://code.google.com/p/twitter-php/
>   http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/twitter-app-oauth-php/

**Edit:**
Just to clarify - It is not possible to do without oauth or the user authorizing the tweet on twitter's website.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately OAuth is really your only option for full API access to your account. It's trivial to get an API key, though, at https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new - and worth the trouble to learn the system IMO.